# i am keeping seeing the dereferncing a null pointer warnning in the line "hiddenLetters[i] = '_';"?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Could someone tell me why i am keeping seeing the error dereferncing a null pointer in the line "hiddenLetters[i] = '_';"??

```
char* hiddenWord(char* guessWord) {

    int length = strlen(guessWord);
    int i;

    char* hiddenLetters = NULL;

    if (!(hiddenLetters = (char*)malloc(length))) {
        printf("Error");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        hiddenLetters[i] = '_';
        printf("%c ", hiddenLetters[i]);
    }

    return hiddenLetters;
}
```

Comment: How is `hiddenLetters` declared?

Comment: char* hiddenLetters = NULL;

Comment: If it is `NULL`, then  `hiddenLetters[i]` is dereferencing an invalid pointer (`NULL + i`)

Comment: You're obviously missing a step - if you intend `hiddenLetters` to point to a dynamic buffer, you need to allocate that buffer using `malloc` or `calloc`, such as `hiddenLetters = malloc( length+1 );` (assuming the buffer needs to store a string).

Comment: If you used the returned pointer as a string, you need to remember that strings in C  are really called ***null-terminated** byte string*. You must add a null.terminator `'\0'` at the end, and must also remember to allocate space for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hiddenLetters` doesn't have any elements until it passes the if check, so returning null if there was an error will suppress the warning.

```c
char* getHiddenWord(char* guessWord) {

    int length = strlen(guessWord);

    char* hiddenLetters;
    
    if (!(hiddenLetters = (char*)malloc(length))) {
        printf("Error");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        hiddenLetters[i] = '_';
        printf("%c ", hiddenLetters[i]);
    }

    return hiddenLetters;
}
```